# Playing sounds from buffer in pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I am trying to play sound from buffer in pygame. I am using Python 3. 
I got uncompressed wav file, sound.wav.

I can play it like this and it works fine:

```
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file='/path/to/file/sound.wav')
sound.play()
```

According to [pygame documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) buffer can be Python 3 bytes object, but if I try:

```
f = open('/path/to/file/sound.wav', 'rb')
data = f.read()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer=data)
sound.play()
```

This code can be run, but sound is deformed.

So, how to use buffer? Documentation is really spare and I couldn't find any examples. I can't play sounds from hard disk because I have many raw audio chunks, which I convert to wav, but saving them on hard disk (and then reading them) is way to slow and inefficient (since I already have them in memory). Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I also tried to play raw audio without header. Fortunately thanks to [@Andris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501814/andris) comment I figure out what pygame means by buffer. I init mixer with `pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=8, channels=1)` so I thought that buffer should be in this format. I dumped on disk what was returned by `pygame.mixer.Sound(file='/path/to/file/sound.wav').get_raw()` and after examination I can say it's raw audio, but with frequency=44100, size=-16.

Comment: You may need to use [get_raw()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_raw) instead of normal file read, otherwise e.g. the wav file header will be played back as well.

Comment: @Andris: get_raw() returns a bytes object in Python 3. Do you know how to convert it back to Sound object in pygame?

Comment: @Peihui: use your rawdata as Sound(rawdata) or Sound(buffer=rawdata) - see the documentation on the possible constructor params. Strangely enough I'm working from documentation only as I have get_buffer().raw only and not get_raw(). (Version mismatch probably.)

Comment: What is your raw audio format (bit width, channel count, sampling rate)? Can mixer be initiated to that format? My attempt at saving the raw data was successful - 10 sec of 44KHz 32 bit stereo was downsampled by mixer with your settings from a 1.76MB wav to 220500 bytes of raw audio as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here a full example from creating an in-memory buffer filled with audio to then playing it back using pygame:

```
import pygame
import subprocess

rawdata = subprocess.check_output([
    'sox', '-n', '-b', '16', '-e', 'signed', '-r', '44100',
    '-c', '1', '-t', 'raw', '-', 'synth', '0.1', 'sin', '700'])
pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency=44100, size=-16, channels=1)
pygame.init()
beep = pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer=rawdata)
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(beep)
pygame.quit()
```

Notice how the raw audio options given to sox (sample rate 44.1k, 16 bit signed, 1 channel) are the same given to the pygame mixer.

Have fun!

Comment: i hear nothing using it : ```python3 --version``` Python 3.8.5 ```pygame``` Version: 1.9.6 under ```Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS```

Answer (score 0):

Use ButesIO for it:

```
import pygame
from io import BytesIO
f=BytesIO(open('data/house_lo.ogg', 'rb').read())
pygame.init()
print(pygame.mixer.Sound(f).get_length())
print(pygame.mixer.Sound(file='data/house_lo.ogg').get_length())

>>> 7.104852676391602
>>> 7.104852676391602
```

Answer get from [GitHub](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/556).

Have a nice day.